# Solspace Calendar - Ordering occurrences by time

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar, calendar

I'm outputting occurrences using the `{occurrences}` variable pair within a `{exp:calendar:events}` tag for a single day and I'd like to sort these occurrences by time.

```
{exp:calendar:events calendar_id="22" date_range_start="2013-11-10" date_range_end="2013-11-10" sort="asc" show_years="9" pad_short_weeks="n"}

   {occurrences}
      {occurrence_start_date format="%D, %F %j %g:%i %a"}
   {/occurrences}

{/exp:calendar:events}
```

I tried using the `sort` parameter in the occurrences variable pair and  but it didn't work. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just ran into a similar issue with Solspace Calendar. The add-on is written so that ordering in this way is not possible (it has a built-in ordering process). You can't even use the `fixed_order=` parameter.

In the end, I had to **utilize Stash to first grab all the event occurrences and set them into a list, then grab that Stash list and sort using Stash**.

So, after you install Stash, try this:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="event_occurrences" parse_tags="yes"}
  {exp:calendar:events calendar_id="22" date_range_start="2013-11-10" date_range_end="2013-11-10" show_years="9" pad_short_weeks="n"}
    {occurrences}
      {stash:occurrence_title}{title}{/stash:occurrence_title}
      {stash:occurrence_start_date_hour}{occurrence_start_date format="%D, %F %j %g:%i %a"}{/stash:occurrence_start_date_hour}
      {stash:occurrence_time_sort}{occurrence_start_date format="%Y%m%d%H%i"}{/stash:occurrence_time_sort}
    {/occurrences}
  {/exp:calendar:events}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Then use Stash to display them in order by sorting according to `{stash:occurrence_time_sort}`

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="event_occurrences" orderby="occurrence_time_sort" sort="desc"}
  <h1>{occurrence_title}</h1>
  <h2>{occurrence_start_date_hour}</h2>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: Looks like a very convoluted way of getting a chronological list of events, when a simple `{exp:calendar:cal}` tag would do the same job. My two cents. :)

Comment: @Solspace, true. :) I had to use this for custom ordering of events (not occurrences). Forgot about the `:cal` tag.

Comment: @Solspace: I think that this is the only way to get events list with one occurrence where the events are grouped and not showed "double/triple" as when using cal tag. as I can see, there is no way for limit-per-event listing in Cal tag.

Comment: @DavorPeic You could do it with {exp:calendar:cal} and some PHP, building an array to prune out "duplicates". Likely a Stash approach is also possible. The other advantage is that everything stays chronological, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to order occurrences chronologically, you should be using `{exp:calendar:cal}`. This is the only tag that will order occurrences in true chronological order. Details on why/how can be found here: http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/getting_started/

Comment: So would the proper form to output occurrences for a day and to have those occurrences ordered by start date:

`{exp:calendar:cal calendar_id="22" date_range_start="2013-11-10" date_range_end="2013-11-10" sort="asc" show_years="9" pad_short_weeks="n"}

{events}

   {occurrences orderby="occurrence_start_date" sort="asc"}
      {occurrence_start_date format="%D, %F %j %g:%i %a"}
   {/occurrences}

{/events}

{/exp:calendar:cal}`

Comment: Close. You don't need `show_years=""` if the timeframe is a specific day. Same for `sort=""`: `{exp:calendar:cal}` is already chronological. Also, `{occurrences}{/occurrences}` (which doesn't accept parameters, btw) is not needed. It would be rather this: `{exp:calendar:cal calendar_id="22" date_range_start="2013-11-10" date_range_end="2013-11-10" pad_short_weeks="n"} {events}  {event_start_date format="%D, %F %j %g:%i %a"} {/events} {/exp:calendar:cal}`